# How to make image field's alt and title attribute values auto filled from token value in Drupal 9

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

In Drupal 9, We have a image field in the content types where we have a option to provide values for alt and title attributes. These values will be used for SEO improvements.

Is there any way or modules available to auto pull content title value for image alt and title attributes? Something like token replacements.

Thanks in advance.

Below is the screenshot for the expectation.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[imagefield_tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_tokens) module helps to accommodate this requirement.

- Add an 'image' field type to any content entity type (node,
  taxonomy, etc...)
- Set Form Display 'Image Field Tokens'
- Set Display format 'Image Field Tokens'
- Save changes.
- Create a new content or change existing content entity.
- Select image in entity edit form.
- Fill 'Title and 'Alt' fields for the image using available tokens
  from the form 'Browse available tokens.'
- Save changes.

Note: In Image - Manage Field - Configure default value as [node:title] to get Content title value in image alt and title attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the token module to see the site tokens in a user interface by going to: admin/help/token

So the token value for the alt field would be something like:

`[node:field_image:alt]`

And for the title:

`[node:field_image:title]`

You can also use them in a custom theme template by using:

```
{{ node.field_image.alt }}
{{ node.field_image.title }}
```

I find using the Metatag module helpful to achieve what you want to do here.

Comment: Hi Gary, Thanks for your Answer. But the above token approach is not working for this case since Available tokens are not eligible for Image alt and title attributes. Please let me know if you have any working examples.

Comment: I'm not fully sure what you mean by "not eligible"? My reply above assumes you are using the core image module. If you are using the core media module then the tokens are slightly different to ensure we pull in the entity data at the same time. Saying that I have many working examples of using tokens and metatags to generate the metadata and schema.org data on my pages. I do also use the token filter module (https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) if I need to make the tokens available in ckeditor. If you can explain more what you are doing, I may be able to be more specific.

Comment: Gary, I have attached the screenshot in the issue description. In my case, I have enabled token module and I am NOT getting the token select link "Browse Available Tokens" either for alt or title attributes within manage image field section. Please let me know if I missed anything to describe more.

Comment: In those fields you should be manually adding the alt tag title tag. You can then use that data using metatag or in your own theme to output them as metadata in the source code.   If you do really want to auto generate those based on tokens, then there is a contributed module that can help with that: https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_tokens - personally I make those fields mandatory and ensure my users fill them in manually. This in my opinion makes for better SEO :)

Comment: Thanks Gary. This module drupal.org/project/imagefield_tokens  fulfilling my need and I can able to place Content title for image alt and title.